# Why does Rust not recognize that I re-assign to the moved variable inside a closure?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am having trouble understanding why a particular pattern is not compiling.

Rust recognizes when I move a variable and then reassign to it outside of a closure and I think properly allows the code to compile, but when I try to do the same in a closure that will be run more than once it will not.

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    v.into_iter().fold(0, |a, b| a + b);
    v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter().for_each(|x| {
        v.into_iter().fold(x, |a, b| a + b);
        v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    });
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
2 |     let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
  |         ----- captured outer variable
...
6 |         v.into_iter().fold(x, |a, b| a + b);
  |         ^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

It seems to me that the reassignment to `v` should satisfy the borrow checker that no variable will be accessed after being moved. Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess: `FnMut` closures can possibly be called multiple times. In this case a `for_each` will execute in sequence, but what if that closure were being passed to multiple threads? You could consume `v` and then other thread try to access it before you can reassign to it. But this is just a wild guess - I'm a Rust newbie myself so I'm not sure.

Comment: @julioolvr I had that thought too, but I believe rust has traits that must be implemented for that to be so. The Send and Sync traits are what tell rust that types can be shared between threads, and for_each does not require either of those types so that should never be possible.

Answer (score 4):

As @Shepmaster mentioned, the fix is to use `std::mem::replace`.

So, what is the difference between:

```
    v.into_iter().fold(x, |a, b| a + b);
    v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
```

and:

```
    let v_old = std::mem::replace(&mut v, vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
    v_old.into_iter().fold(x, |a, b| a + b);
```

?

In two words: **exception safety**.

If, for some reason, the expression `v.into_iter().fold(...)` would panic, it would leave `v` moved out and the next statement would never be executed.

This is perfectly acceptable in a `FnOnce`, as you will never call the closure another time, but not acceptable in a `FnMut` or `Fn` as on the next call... *what would you do with `v`*?

On the other hand, using `std::mem::replace`, you swap *first* and *then* execute the potentially panicking operation. If the operation does panic, then all that is left "moved out" is a temporary variable which disappears at the end of the stack frame anyway. No issue.

Answer (score 2):

> the reassignment to `v` should satisfy the borrow checker that no variable will be accessed after being moved

Pay attention to the error message details — there isn't a move to start with:

> ```
> cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
> ```

Since there was no move out, it doesn't make sense to move something back in.

Instead, you can replace the value through the mutable reference and consume the old value:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter().for_each(move |x| {
        let v_old = std::mem::replace(&mut v, vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
        v_old.into_iter().fold(x, |a, b| a + b);
    });
}
```